# How to compare the survival curves for three groups using (Gehan's test and Tarone and Ware weights)

Tags: r

I am trying to to compare the survival curves for three groups in the data in the following picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BjFj.png)

First of all, I run the following code to define the data:

```
time_Untreated<- c(20, 21, 23, 24, 24, 26, 26, 27, 28, 30)
```

`censor_Untreated<- c(rep(1,10), rep(0,0))
censor_Untreated`

`time_Radiated<- c(26,28, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 35)
censor_Radiated<- c(rep(1,9), rep(0,1))
censor_Radiated`

`time_Radiated_BPA<- c(31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 38, 38, 39, 42, 42)
censor_Radiated_BPA<- c(rep(1,8), rep(0,2))
censor_Radiated_BPA`

Then, I tried to combine the 3 groups in one code so that I could compare the survival curves of the 3 groups. I used the following code:

```
library(KMsurv)
```

`library(survival)
library(coin)`

`KM.fit.Untreated<-survfit(Surv(time_Untreated,censor_Untreated)~1, conf.type="none")
plot(KM.fit.Untreated,lty =1:3, lwd=c(3,3,3), col=c(1,4,10), xlab="U", ylab = "Survival")
legend(1500, 0.95, c("g = 1, Untreated", "g = 2, Radiated", "g=3, BPA"), lty=1:3, lwd=c(3,3,3),col = c(1,4,10))`

`KM.fit.Radiated<-survfit(Surv(time_Radiated,censor_Radiated)~1, conf.type="none")
plot(KM.fit.Radiated,lty =1:3, lwd=c(3,3,3), col=c(1,4,10), xlab="R", ylab = "Survival")
legend(1500, 0.95, c("g = 1, Untreated", "g = 2, Radiated", "g=3, BPA"), lty=1:3, lwd=c(3,3,3),col = c(1,4,10))`

`KM.fit.Radiated_BPA<-survfit(Surv(time_Radiated_BPA,censor_Radiated_BPA)~1, conf.type="none")
plot(KM.fit.Radiated_BPA,lty =1:3, lwd=c(3,3,3), col=c(1,4,10), xlab="B", ylab = "Survival")
legend(1500, 0.95, c("g = 1, Untreated", "g = 2, Radiated", "g=3, BPA"), lty=1:3, lwd=c(3,3,3),col = c(1,4,10))`

`##logrank using the formulas##
test.Untreated<-survdiff(Surv(time_Untreated,censor_Untreated)~1)
test.Untreated`

`test.Radiated<-survdiff(Surv(time_Radiated,censor_Radiated)~1)
test.Radiated`

`test.Radiated_BPA<-survdiff(Surv(time_Radiated_BPA,censor_Radiated_BPA)~1)
test.Radiated_BPA`

The problem is I'm getting an error message when I run the last code (logrank using the formulas), which is Error in survdiff(Surv(time_Untreated, censor_Untreated) ~ 1) : 
  No groups to test

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You need a group to test. You can't test the overall survival on its own.

Comment: You need to setup the data better. Put all survival times in one column, then all status in another, then another column for the treatment group. Then do everything in one command: `survdiff(Surv(time, event)~group)`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Could you please clarify that more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the data in long format, something like this:

```
myData <- data.frame(time=c(time_Untreated, time_Radiated, time_Radiated_BPA),
                     status=c(censor_Untreated, censor_Radiated, censor_Radiated_BPA),
                     group= rep(1:3, each=10))
str(myData)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ time  : num  20 21 23 24 24 26 26 27 28 30 ...
 $ status: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ group : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

survdiff(Surv(time, status)~group, data=myData)
```

---

```
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ group, data = myData)

         N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
group=1 10       10     2.66    20.300    27.365
group=2 10        9     7.60     0.258     0.431
group=3 10        8    16.74     4.566    16.587

 Chisq= 33.4  on 2 degrees of freedom, p= 6e-08

KM.fit <- survfit(Surv(time,status)~group, data=myData, conf.type="none")

cols <- c(1,4,10)
plot(KM.fit, lty=1:3, lwd=3, col=cols, xlab="U", ylab = "Survival")
legend('bottomleft', c("g = 1, Untreated", "g = 2, Radiated", "g=3, BPA"), lty=1:3, lwd=3, col = cols, bty="n")
```

---

If I've switched the status values, just change them when you create the vectors. For example,

```
censor_Untreated <- c(rep(0,10), rep(1,0))
```

Because normally the outcome in survival analysis is an event which is coded as `1`. A `0` means censored. R allows three different versions. 0/1, 1/2, or FALSE/TRUE. See the help page of `Surv`.